# Calling class with parameters in Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Distance{
    int feet,inches;
    public:
    Distance (int feet,int inches){
        this->feet=feet;
        this->inches=inches;
    }
    Distance operator-(){
        this->feet=-(this->feet);
        this->inches=-(this->inches);
        return Distance(feet,inches);
        // return *this; 
    }
    void show(){
        cout << "Value of feet is " << this->feet <<endl;
        cout << "Value of inches is " << this->inches << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Distance d1(90,80);
    -d1;
    d1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt pertains to this line of code:

```
return Distance(feet,inches);
```

Over here, how are we calling the constructor without creating an object of class Distance, can we call the constructor for a class as well?

In my opinion, this line should have been something like this:

```
Distance d1;
return d1(feet,inches);
```

Comment: `how are we calling the constructor without creating an object of class Distance, can we call the constructor for a class as well?` This line __is__ creating an object.

Comment: Your operator is doing something it shouldn't do: Modify its own object! You need to create a new object *first* and set the new values on that object. I recommend that you make the whole function `const`, as in `Distance operator-() const`.

Comment: @tkausl Can you tell me what is the name of the new object that is getting created?

Comment: @tkausl As far as I know, the syntax for creating an object is class-name followed by object-name

Comment: It doesn't have a name.

Comment: But here we don't have the object name, and this is what is confusing me

Comment: @tkausl Is it possible to have an object without a name? Sounds weird.

Comment: `Distance(feet,inches)` creates a *temporary* object, handled by the compiler itself. It doesn't have a "name" until you assign it to a variable. As in `some_distance = Distance(feet,inches);`

Comment: On another and totally unrelated note, I suggest you keep only the distance in inches inside your class. That will make it much easier to handle when you start implementing arithmetic operators (like addition and subtraction). Only convert to feet when displaying the distance.

Comment: Sidenote: [P1935R0
A C++ Approach to Physical Units](https://mpusz.github.io/wg21-papers/papers/1935R0_a_cpp_approach_to_physical_units.html) has an interesting list of implementations dealing with physical units. If you need something that works you may find what you need in there.